# AWS RDS Postgres pg_hba.conf auth-method

Tags: amazon-rds, authentication, aws, pgadmin, password

I'm starting to use Amazon Web Service's Relational Database Server product (AWS RDS) and want to confirm I have not made a security blunder.

My configuration:

- Postgres
- Publicly accessible
- Inbound rule on security group added for "PostgreSQL / My IP"

These options enable me to use pgAdmin to connect and populate data.  I've tried to determine the auth-method used in AWS RDS Postgres without success.

**Am I transmitting my [password in clear text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html) when I connect with pgAdmin?**

---

**Edit:**

I'm starting to think my fears are warranted.  This is what I've learned:

- Directions for [Using SSL with PostgreSQL DB Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL) suggests it's not the default
- The 'SSL' option in my pgAdmin connection properties has no options (prob'ly because I haven't setup certificates)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, **SSL is usually being used**.  What varies is the level to which server certificates are verified.

Reading the [guide from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL) is helpful albeit lengthy.

Things to remember...

1. To determine if SSL is on (apparently this requires a plugin but works by default on AWS RDS):

   > show ssl;
2. There is a ~/.pgpass file that automatically supplies passwords when using psql (this confused me for a while)
3. Full server certificate verification (requires the [root cert from AWS](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem)):

   > $ psql -h testpg.cdhmuqifdpib.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 "dbname=testpg user=testuser sslrootcert=rds-ca-2015-root.pem sslmode=verify-full"
4. SSL is still on with this command however (no sslmode,sslrootcert):

   > $ psql -h testpg.cdhmuqifdpib.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 "dbname=testpg user=testuser"
5. This will not connect because root cert is not supplied:

   > $ psql -h testpg.cdhmuqifdpib.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 "dbname=testpg user=testuser sslmode=verify-full"
6. I never established a non-SSL connection however it is possible to prevent non-SSL connections to a DB instance with a parameter on the server: *rds.force_ssl*